# WiFi Connectivity Diagnosis

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I have a MacBook Pro on Yosemite 10.10.2. Whenever I come home from work with it and try to connect to my home network, I see this image:

[image]

When I unplug and plug back in my router, it works. An iPhone, iPad, and iMac all connect with no issues.

More information: Router is ISP provided, ZyXel PK5000Z, and is about 3 years old. Its firmware is up to date. Sessions are 40/8000, 22% of memory is used, and it is on the router-identified 'best' channel. My computer can find 18 other networks in range, and the router is 2.4GHz.

Is there something else I could do next time it fails to find out why it's not working?

**EDIT**

Here is the output of a verbosely logged connection attempt:

https://gist.github.com/alexmcpherson/a4470173c4f24fb07a05

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting connected just fine at the Wi-Fi/802.11 link layer, but not getting a DHCP lease.

The output of `ipconfig getpacket en0` might be helpful.

It would be helpful to know if clicking "Renew DHCP Lease" helps. It's in System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > TCP/IP.

Turning on `sudo ipconfig setverbose 1` and then watching for log files in `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/` named `com.apple.networking.IPConfiguration.log.<timestamp>`. syslog might help as well. Note that that command is not persistent across reboots, so if you have to reboot between now and the next time you see the problem, you'll need to remember to run that command after reboot so that the verbose logging is already happening when the problem reproduces. You can't get the information you want if you try to turn it on after the fact.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look next time it craps out (perhaps tonight) and will let you know. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Ok! I finally got into verbose mode and dumped some logs during a connection attempt, here is the output in a gist: https://gist.github.com/alexmcpherson/a4470173c4f24fb07a05

Comment: Oops! I gave you wrong information on how to enable verbose DHCP logging and harvest the logs. I'll update my Answer to correct it.

Comment: Ok, here is a more verbose log I was able to capture, of a minute long scan that resulted in that '!' wifi: https://gist.github.com/alexmcpherson/bc43b04bab61c7ff9229

Comment: Well, that looks like your DHCP client is doing all the right things to ask for an address, but not getting a response. It's possible the packets aren't getting through, so the next time this happens, put your Mac on a static IP address config (one that you've tested ahead of time and you know works), and see if your connectivity works. If it does, then it's probably just your router's DHCP service screwing up and not sending a response.